# How can I get my custom Unity editor menu items to work if they're in a package?

Tags: unity, editors, menu

I'm trying to get new items to appear in Unity's **Assets→Create** menu.

[image: Screenshot of Assets menu in Unity editor]

I'm defining these inside another project which is referenced as a package. The general goal here is to share my editor scripts a bit more easily than people having to import a package archive.

The setup is as follows:

- Main project, HakanaiShaderCommonsExamples, references HakanaiShaderCommons as a package (currently by a local directory reference, actual production version references it by git URL, as seen [here](https://github.com/ephemeral-laboratories/HakanaiShaderCommonsExamples/blob/main/Packages/manifest.json#L20).)

  [image: Screenshot of Packages section in Unity editor]
- In `HakanaiShaderCommons/Scripts/Editor/CreationMenu.cs` I have added my top-level static methods for the menu items:

  ```csharp
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEditor;

  namespace HakanaiShaderCommons
  {
      public static class CreationMenu
      {
          [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Hakanai Shader/Raycast Shader", false, 100)]
          public static void CreateRaycastShader()
          {
          }

          [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Hakanai Shader/Raymarch Shader", false, 101)]
          public static void CreateRaymarchShader()
          {
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- In `HakanaiShaderCommons/Scripts/Editor/Unity.HakanaiShaderCommons.Editor.asmdef` (which I learned I need only just today), I have:

  ```json
  {
    "name": "Unity.HakanaiShaderCommons.Editor",
    "references": [
    ],
    "includePlatforms": [
      "Editor"
    ],
    "excludePlatforms": [],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [
    ],
    "noEngineReferences": false
  }
  ```

Back in Unity, my items don't appear in the menu. But I also get no errors to indicate what might have gone wrong.

If I compare what I'm doing to TextMeshPro, whose menu item *is* working, I can't figure out what's different about mine compared to theirs, other than their `.asmdef` file referring to their dependencies.

What is the trick here?

I know it is not:

- The package name / namespace of my script, because TextMeshPro have `TMPro` as their namespace even though the assembly is named `Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor`.